# Inverted weekday range in cron for @Scheduled?

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I want to execute a task at specific hours from Friday till Monday.

Having specified like that

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 15-23 * * FRI-MON", zone = "CET")
```

I receive an exception of type `IllegalStateException`

```
Invalid inverted range: '5-1' in expression "0 0/30 15-23 * * FRI-MON"
```

My workaround is currently to specify those days by separating them with commas.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 15-23 * * FRI,SAT,SUN,MON", zone = "CET")
```

I would like to be able to write it shorter as an inverted range though. Is there any possibility to do so? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try
"0 0/30 15-23 * * 1,5-7" if that's short enough. 
(0 as well as 7 maps to Sunday).